# Wordpress twentysixteen theme removing all the unnecessary spacing in theme

Tags: css, wordpress

Basically this is one question but might need a multi part answer to remove the excess spacing. Basically the problem occurs when setting the featured image on a post on the default twentysixteen theme. I have a live test environment setup to show this here: http://192.241.239.174/index.php/2016/11/02/hello-world/

Here is a shot of how it currently is vs what I'm expecting it to look like: http://prntscr.com/d204p5

Thank you for any help

Edit: Further researching similar questions I have gotten slightly closer by using some custom css to change the thumbnail/featured image max width to 150 which should be fine as all my featured images are going to be 150x150 anyways. This code was added into custom css:

```
.post-thumbnail img {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 15px 10px 0;
    max-width: 150px;
}
```

Now the text does appear slightly higher but still fails to wrap the thumbnail and is still not close enough to the thumbnail. I'd like to have the text closer to the thumbnail

EDIT: Complete solution
The complete solution I used was adding this code into my custom css:

```
.entry-footer {
    display: none;
}

.post-thumbnail img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 20px 0px 0;
    max-width: 150px;
}

body:not(.search-results) article:not(.type-page) .entry-content {
     float: none !important; 
     width: 100%;
}


.entry-content > :last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think that's the better choice to make in fact i would have setup a child theme and worked on it, by the way:

```
.entry-footer {
    display: none;
}

.post-thumbnail img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 20px 0px 0;
    max-width: 150px;
}

body:not(.search-results) article:not(.type-page) .entry-content {
     float: none !important; 
     width: 100% !important;
}

.entry-content > :last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You may need to add !important keyword if something doesn't work.
The result: [Is that like what you wanted?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbdGq.png)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes I think I will add that to the child theme of the target site. I'm currently using the "simple custom css" plugin to tinker with it until I get things figured out. I enter the css you suggested but as you can see on the test environment the text is not wrapping the thumbnail and still padding far from the thumbnail. The part of the css `.entry-content` mentions child maybe this is causing the hang up when im putting it into simple custom css?

Comment: sorry: body:not(.search-results) article:not(.type-page) .entry-content {
     float: none; 
}

Comment: Is `.entry-content` not needed anymore? I see the text is now wrapped but no longer displays up to the sidebar on the right (blank space shifted to the right now) Do you have a suggestion for that? Thank you, you've been extremely helpful Sid!

Comment: I just edited, try to add width:100% to entry-content and tell me if only with :last child it works or not, thank you

Comment: This is what the custom css looks like right now after making the changes you described: http://pastebin.com/BPTTnJnv
I tried it with and without the :last child
neither seem to take affect.

Comment: Also I added `width: 100%; !important`so it looks like this now: http://pastebin.com/h4kBHzT1 it seems like there is no affect with or without the :last child

Comment: Sid I copied and pasted it from your updated code no change it seems. This is what it looks like now: http://prntscr.com/d21qro

Comment: Are you sure that you added the 100% width? because it seems to not have it saved

Comment: Sid you were right. If you update your answer i'll mark it as the solution. Thank you so much Sid i've updated the initial question so that you know what I have in the css file that I used as your solution. Thanks again.